# how merge two arrays in this case to hash with ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am ruby beginner.

the case example:

```
 array1: ['A', 'ww','g']

 array2: ['dsdsdsds','A', 'ww','jgjhgj', 'g']
```

merged hash map should be:

```
 outputHashArray:  { 'dsdsdsds'=>'','A'=>'appers', 'ww'=>'appers','jgjhgj'=>'', 'g'=>'appers' }
```

thanks

Comment: Where does `appers` come from?

Comment: Your `outputHashArray` is neither a hash nor an array. This syntax is invalid.

Comment: ok, its hash, which syntax its should be?

Comment: You had outputHashArray  defined with [ ], as an Array. I updated the example to be valid, so that it is a Hash with { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want is something like this:

```
 Hash[array2.map { |x| [x, array1.include?(x) ? 'appers' : ''] }]
```

Comment: Thanks,why need to put inside Hash [] ?

Comment: That creates a Hash using a key/value array.

Comment: @Yosef: You can also leave it away, which would give you an array. Maybe that's what you need, we can't know.